# Is there a command for the "Workspace Switcher"?

Tags: 11.04, unity, command-line

I just learned about "whereis" in terminal as a way to find a command to launch a given application. However, I still can't find (a way to find) the **command** to launch the "**Workspace Switcher**" in natty / unity.

I'd be interested in **both** the method(s) for finding the command **as well as** the command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CompizConfig Settings Manager** > Expo plugin > **Expo key**

wow, after all this time... was it really THAT simple ?

;-D

ps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYxJSRqXz8k

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a command for absolutely everything. But in this case, "Workspace switcher" can be triggered with a keyboard shortcut (super+s) which can also be sent using a tool called "xdotool", via the command line.

So install xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

And then you can trigger the Workspace Switcher from a terminal using:

```
xdotool key super+s
```

Comment: Thanks Alin, glad to know there's a way. I'm not sure if I'll pursue it though... am not too keen to install extra packages only to get some small extra features...

Comment: I also tried unsticking and unlocking the workspace-switcher icon in gconf-editor, but nothing changed: I still can't move the icon around, ie higher up and more "in reach". (I didn't reboot yet since - if that might affect the change?) Any clues?

Comment: You can move icons by dragging them to the right, then up/down and then back to the left on the launcher.

Comment: This does _NOT_ work with the bottom icons: Workspace Switcher, ... , Trash. At least not on my system; does it work on yours?

Comment: Oh yes, you can't move those... I misunderstood what you said, sorry.